# BIRT Report Ad Hoc Queries

Tags: birt, adhoc, page-break, adhoc-queries

When users create an Ad Hoc BIRT report and download it to an Excel spreadsheet the default is 40 rows/sheet. I want the default to be 0, which means that it will download all the rows to 1 sheet. I know that the solution is setPageBreakInterval(0), but don't know where to set it up for the users.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a table:

1. select your table,
2. then go in the properties
3. avoid all (before, inside, after)
4. set the page break interval to 0

Should do :

[image]

Comment: Your idea works great if I'm creating a report in my IDE. The problem is that users don't have access to an IDE when they're creating an ad hoc report. I sent a query to IBM and their answer was "Unfortunately, it is not possible to do this setup for Ad Hoc reports."

Comment: Ok, and what about create a template?